# RSA verification failed when I use some code from xlnx uboot

Tags: c, encryption, rsa, verify

I'm trying porting some code to do RSA verification. I googled ,and found some code in [xlnx u-boot](https://github.com/Xilinx/u-boot-xlnx/blob/master/lib/rsa/rsa-mod-exp.c) .
I put this rsa-mod-exp.c in my code and of course with some other .h files. My SOC is little endian ,so I use the little endian definitions.
After all above are done , I try to create a signature to verify my code. 
Before that , I noticed that the u-boot rsa structure is different from openssl RSA structure. So to get the u-boot rsa structure , I need to install a tool called dumppublickey . I found one from [here](https://github.com/tgalal/android-dumpkey) and installed.

```
OpenSSL RSA public key structure:

struct {
BIGNUM *n; // public modulus
BIGNUM *e; // public exponent
BIGNUM *d; // private exponent
BIGNUM *p; // secret prime factor
BIGNUM *q; // secret prime factor
BIGNUM *dmp1; // d mod (p-1)
BIGNUM *dmq1; // d mod (q-1)
BIGNUM *iqmp; // q^-1 mod p
// ...
};RSA
U-boot RSA public key structure:

struct rsa_public_key {
uint len; /* len of modulus[] in number of uint32_t */
uint32_t n0inv; /* -1 / modulus[0] mod 2^32 */
uint32_t modulus; / modulus as little endian array */
uint32_t rr; / R^2 as little endian array */
uint64_t exponent; /* public exponent */
};
```

Now, every thing is ready beside a signature. Here is the step I create my signature.

```
1. Create private key.It's a 2048 bit and the public exponent is three.  
openssl genpkey -algorithm RSA -out key.pem -pkeyopt rsa_keygen_bits:2048 -pkeyopt rsa_keygen_pubexp:3  
2. Create cert file.  
openssl req -new -x509 -key key.pem -out newcert.pem -days 3650  
3. Get the U-boot structure public key.  
dumppublickey  newcert.pem  
I got :
    {
    64,    //lenth
    0x63b40d47,   //n0inv
    {2799858569,......,1105502226,1577608370,1150603850,3030884821},  // modules (N)
    {909785043,.......,3050452165,3418434484,2529136815,837355943},      // r^2
    3   //exponent
    }  
4. Sign my file using the private key.  
echo "hello world" > a.txt  
openssl dgst -sign key.pem -sha256 -hex a.txt
I got :
    RSA-SHA256(a.txt)= 157eb60ad0c77427cd....6b02b5d331d610b27f32aaa0
```

I put key length, n0inv, modulus, rr, exponent and the signature in my code. Notice that modulus and rr I useu_int32 array like I showed above while signature I use a u_int8 array like below.

```
{0x15,0x7e.0xb6,0x0a,.......0xaa,0xa0}
```

Here is what I think the rsa-mod-exp.c (function rsa_mod_exp_sw) will give me . I thought I will get the result of the sha256 hash value of file a.txt. Same as the result I did using openssl.

```
openssl dgst -sha256 a.txt
```

However, I did't get this sha256 hash value . I got something strange.
Could anyone point which part is wrong and how to correct it ?

Answer (score 0):

It seems `struct key_prop` argument of `rsa_mod_exp_sw` assumes that modulus and rr are big-endian.
So modulus and rr generated by `dumppublickey` should be converted to big-endian.
I could decrypt sign and confirmed that decrypted data contains pkcs v1.5 padding format.